# Where can I buy stock photographs to use on my non-profit website

Tags: web, stock-photography

I am looking for images of people meeting, talking, on computers and off, with cell phones, outdoors, indoors for use in a young educational website and am willing to pay $10 - $20 each. Its hard to find a good site to buy from as there are so many out there. Any recommendation(s) would be helpful.

Comment: This is off-topic; the site is about the _creation_ side of photography.

Comment: If you need stock photos, there are far better places to find that kind of thing than here. PhotoSE is a place to discuss the artistic and technical aspects of photography, not troll for links to stock photo sites (Google and Bing are your best friends there.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is off-topic here, but simple Google "stock images for non-profit".  For example this has a good overview

[Quality, affordable choices for your nonprofit](http://www.socialbrite.org/2010/08/12/top-10-sites-for-free-or-low-cost-photos/)

Answer (score 4):

Just go to flickr and look for creative commons licensed shots that allow commercial use. You'll find some that require attribution. So use and correctly give the attribution.

Answer (score 1):

I can't post comments yet so i will have to make this suggestion an answer- 
 I found many good images for free from sxc.hu (I'm not sure what the license for these photos are as I haven't used any images in a way that may have licensing issues & it depends on each photographer)